# Laravel sending data from Event to Listener and getting Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0] error

Tags: laravel

in `Laravel` 7 i have 2 event such as sending activation code and payment `order_id`, sending activation code work fine but sending order_id don't work and i get this error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $code ]] in class App\Listeners\PaymentTransactionListener
```

`EventServiceProvider` class content:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserAuthenticate' => [
        'App\Listeners\SMSNotification',
    ],
    'App\Events\PaymentTransactionEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\PaymentTransactionListener',
    ],
];
```

testing event:

```
Route::get('/pass',function(){
    event(new PaymentTransactionEvent(12,123456,'this is only test'));
});
```

`event` class:

```
class PaymentTransactionEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $code;
    private $orderId;
    private $storeTitle;

    private $smsPanelUsername;
    private $smsPanelPassword;
    private $smsPanelTelNumber;

    public function __construct($code, $orderId,$storeTitle)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->order_id = $orderId;
        $this->storeTitle = $storeTitle;

        $this->smsPanelUsername = '...';//$smsPanel->username;
        $this->smsPanelPassword = '...';//$smsPanel->password;
        $this->smsPanelTelNumber = '...';//$smsPanel->tel_number;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('payment-transaction-event');
    }
}
```

`listener` class:

```
class PaymentTransactionListener
{
    private $code;
    private $orderId;
    private $storeTitle;

    public function __construct($code, $orderId, $storeTitle)
    {
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->orderId = $orderId;
        $this->storeTitle = $storeTitle;
    }

    public function handle(UserAuthenticate $event)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

how can i solve this problem? i think i passed `$code` inside `listener`.

below commands couldn't help me to solve that:

```
php artisan optimize:clear

php artisan clear-compiled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener's constructor is not passed anything. The parameters of the constructor are only used for Dependency Injection. The data you want is part of the Event that is passed to the `handle` method. That is the point of the Event as a container for this information.

You should make the member variables `public` on your Event not `private` so that your Listener can access them.

```
class PaymentTransactionListener
{
    public function handle(PaymentTransactionEvent $event)
    {
        $event->code;
        $event->orderId;
        ...
    }
}
```